# Scroll to Same Amount on Page Return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I successfully implement the following scenario:

I have a php page that sends `post` data to another page, which executes a `MySql` statement. On completion the page redirects to the previous page.

```
header("location: {$_SERVER['HTTP-REFERER']}");
```

The problem is once the page redirects it 'jumps' to the top of the page (this is normal). I need the page to load at its previous scroll amount.

I've looked at [scroll sneak](http://mrcoles.com/scroll-sneak/) but this requires that the same page is directly loaded. Also, I am struggling to find decent how to's.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you've got two solutions:

1. Store the current `scrollTop` value in `localStorage`. This is the easiest way. The downside? Not IE8 and earlier compatible.
2. Send the `scrollTop` value in a variable to the server, so it can store it back when you reload the page and use it to position the scroll.

**First method**:

```
//just before submit
localStorage.setItem('scrollTop', $(window).scrollTop());
//...
//in the page load
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollTop = localStorage.getItem('scrollTop');
    if (scrollTop !== null) {
        $(window).scrollTop(Number(scrollTop));
        localStorage.removeItem('scrollTop');
    }
    ...
});
```

**Second method**

```
<!--include a hidden input in your form -->
<input type="hidden" name="scrollTop" id="scrollTop" value="<?php isset($_POST['scrollTop']) ? $_POST['scrollTop'] : ""; ?>" />
```

If the `scrollTop` value was sent to the server, put it into this hidden field. Then, with javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var scrollTop = $('#scrollTop').val();
     $(window).scrollTop(Number(scrollTop));
     ...
});
....
//before form submit
$('#scrollTop').val($(window).scrollTop()); //the current scrollTop value will be sent to the server
```

Just like that. Of course, if you use the server approach you may have to use session variables if you perform redirects. You may also have to tweak this a bit if you're using AJAX, but I hope you get the idea. Use the approach that better suits yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have a page that refreshes itself every 20 seconds, and upon each submission it grabs the current position and puts it into a hidden field with the id `scrollPosition`:

```
$("#scrollPosition").val($(window).scrollTop());
```

The server-side code handles this parameter and stores its value in the same hidden field and then sets the current scroll location based on this value:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    setInterval("submitRefresh()", 20000); 
    $(window).scrollTop(parseInt($("#scrollPosition").val(), 10));
});
```

Basically, I pass the current position as a parameter and then call `$(window).scrollTop(offset);` with that parameter's value

Answer (score 0):

Post your current location along with the form:

```
$('#form #somefield').val($(window).scrollTop()); // Current page
```

Once you refresh the page get the parameter back and pass it to js and set scroll.

```
var top = 'SomePostParamFromServer';
$(window).scrollTop( parseInt(top )); // New page
```